# Asp.net core MVC (C#, Sql and EF core)

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to this field, please help me on the below query.

I am creating a stock management website which has an admin panel where we can create Categories, Sub Categories and Products. Now I need a Purchase and Sell Module along with a Stock Module. What I want is When I purchase a product i want my stock to be incremented and decremented while selling the same.

I have reached a point where I am stuck on Purchase module which consists of Purchase ID , Category ID , Main Category ID , Product ID, Quantity , Cost Price. I have just purchased 5 quantity of a book. How do I now save that to stock module , please help me what I want to do further

Comment: Will be nice if you provide some code

Comment: perhaps something like `context.Stock.First(s => s.Productid == ...).Quantity -= purchase.Quantity` ?

Comment: What is your specific problem? Or show us part of the code so we can help you solve the problem? We guess, it should not be on the operation of CURD, right?

Comment: I am creating an Inventory/Stock management website in asp.net core mvc using C#, Ef core and Sql. I want modules : Product , Purchase and Sell . So we can purchase products from suppliers , save the quantity somewhere and when we sell products in Sell module, I must know how much quantity of that product is available in stock then I can proceed with selling it. So Im not sure how I can implement this :(